# Global name 'root not defined', tkinter, python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, global-variables

Very new to python and wanted to create a GUI window that i plan to use for a Query tool later. I keep getting global name root not defined error. I am trying to create a user interface that has a window. I probably am missing Object concepts.  Need some help. Thanks. Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *


class GUI(Frame):
"""A Graphical User Interface Class for building a GUI Frame.

Attributes:
    master : 
"""

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.menubar()
        self.label()
        self.onExit()


    def menubar(self):
        self.menubar = Menu(root)
        self.menubar.add_command(label="File")
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        root.config(menu=self.menubar)


    def label(self):
        L0 = Label(text="Use this tool to find the lake location.").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        L1 = Label(text="Lake name :").grid(row = 2)
        L2 = Label(text="County name :").grid(row = 3)

        E0 = Entry().grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        E1 = Entry().grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        B0 = Button(text="Search").grid(row = 6, column = 2)

        if self.E0 and self.E1==null:
            raise RuntimeError('Entry cannot be blank.')


    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x200")
    root.title(" Locator (L^3)")
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The name `root` is local to the function `main` and therefore cannot be seen from other functions.

Comment: your indentation is messed up in your question -- the methods have the same indentation level as `class GUI(Frame)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def menubar(self):
    self.menubar = Menu(root)
    self.menubar.add_command(label="File")
    self.menubar.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
    root.config(menu=self.menubar)
```

`root` doesn't exist here. You either need to make `root` a global variable (bad idea) or pass root to the `GUI` class and save a reference to it.

Something like

```
def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.grid()
    self.menubar()
    self.label()
    self.onExit()

def menubar(self):
    self.menubar = Menu(self.master)
    self.menubar.add_command(label="File")
    self.menubar.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
    self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)
```