# NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a simple GUI application to manage unknown words when learning a new language. I am trying to handle the window close event. I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 171, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/Vocabulary.py", line 162, in main
    Vocabulary(root)
  File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/Vocabulary/vocabulary.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.root = root
NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is what I have done:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Vocabulary.py
#   GUI program to manage unknown words

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Word:

    def __init__(self, wordorphrase, explanation, translation, example):
        self.wordorphrase = wordorphrase
        self.explanation = explanation
        self.example = example
        self.translation = translation

class Vocabulary(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.master.title("Vocabulary")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.words = []
        self.root = root

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.buttons_frame.grid(row = 10, sticky = W)

        self.search_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.search_frame.grid(row = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2)

        self.comboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.search_frame,
                                     width = 3)
        self.comboBox.grid(row = 0, column = 14, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Add = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                              text = 'Add',
                              command = self.add_item)
        self.btn_Add.grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Remove = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                 text = 'Remove',
                                 command = self.remove_item)

        self.btn_Remove.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Edit = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Edit',
                               command = self.edit_item)
        self.btn_Edit.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Save = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Save',
                               command = self.save_item)
        self.btn_Save.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Refresh = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Refresh',
                               command = self.refresh_all)
        self.btn_Refresh.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W)

        self.lblSearch = Label(self.search_frame, text = 'SEARCH: ')
        self.lblSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Search = Text(self.search_frame,
                               height = 1,
                               width = 70)
        self.txt_Search.grid(row = 0, column = 6, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

        self.lblWordsOrPhrases = Label(self.master, text = 'WORDS/PHRASES:')
        self.lblWordsOrPhrases.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.lblWordOrPhrase = Label(self.master, text = 'Word or phrase:')
        self.lblWordOrPhrase.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,
                               selectmode='multiple',
                               height = 34,
                               width = 38)
        self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase = Text(self.master,
                                height = 1,
                                width = 40)
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExplanation = Label(self.master, text = 'Explanation:')
        self.lblExplanation.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Explanation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Explanation.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblTranslation = Label(self.master, text = 'Translation:')
        self.lblTranslation.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Translation = Text(self.master,
                               height = 10,
                               width = 40)
        self.txt_Translation.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExamples = Label(self.master, text = 'Example(s):')
        self.lblExamples.grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Example = Text(self.master,
                                height = 10,
                                width = 40)
        self.txt_Example.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = S)

    def get_word(self):
        return self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_explanation(self):
        return self.txt_Explanation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_translation(self):
        return self.txt_Translation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_example(self):
        return self.txt_Example.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def add_item(self):

        w = Word(self.get_word(), self.get_explanation(), self.get_translation(), self.get_example())

        self.words.append(w)

        self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)

        self.clear_all()

    def remove_item(self):

        self.listBox.delete(ANCHOR)
        self.words.remove()

    def edit_item(self):
        pass

    def save_item(self):
        pass

    def clear_all(self):
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Explanation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Translation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Example.delete('1.0', END)

    def refresh_all(self):
        pass


def main():
    root = Tk()
    Vocabulary(root)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    root.mainloop()

def on_closing():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
        root.destroy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Someone suggested making root a global variable (bad idea) or passing root to the Vocabulary class and saving a reference to it. How do I do that?

Comment: have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890931/global-name-root-not-defined-tkinter-python

Comment: You could indent `on_closing` function within `main`

Comment: I don't understand. I'm new to Python, could you show me how to access root in my example?

Comment: Your code has many syntax errrors ( missing `:` , `Tkinter` not `tkinter` , and mabe more )

Comment: It's tkinter in Python 3.5. Sorry about `:`

Comment: As a note on question writing... the problem can be demonstrated with a much simpler example and you will get more people willing to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Someone suggested [...] passing root to the Vocabulary class and saving a reference to it.

Well, you already did so.
In your example, you passed root as an argument upon creating the instance of `Vocabulary`:

```
Vocabulary(root)
```

Which you can then use as `master` in your code because it is the name of your argument.

```
def __init__(self, master):
```

In your case, your root is now `self.master`:

```
 self.master = master
```

So you can safely remove `self.root = root` and use `self.master` as a reference to root.

---

**EDIT**  (response to comment)

I think it would be a better idea to make `on_closing` a method of `Vocabulary`, like this you can access the root through `self.master`. Also, it seems like the problem is that you forgot the parentheses after `destroy` to actually execute the function. Working code:

```
# Vocabulary.py
# GUI program to manage unknown words

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Word:

    def __init__(self, wordorphrase, explanation, translation, example):
        self.wordorphrase = wordorphrase
        self.explanation = explanation
        self.example = example
        self.translation = translation

class Vocabulary(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.master.title("Vocabulary")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.words = []

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.buttons_frame.grid(row = 10, sticky = W)

        self.search_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.search_frame.grid(row = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2)

        self.comboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.search_frame,
                                     width = 3)
        self.comboBox.grid(row = 0, column = 14, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Add = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                              text = 'Add',
                              command = self.add_item)
        self.btn_Add.grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Remove = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                 text = 'Remove',
                                 command = self.remove_item)

        self.btn_Remove.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Edit = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Edit',
                               command = self.edit_item)
        self.btn_Edit.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Save = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Save',
                               command = self.save_item)
        self.btn_Save.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Refresh = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Refresh',
                               command = self.refresh_all)
        self.btn_Refresh.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W)

        self.lblSearch = Label(self.search_frame, text = 'SEARCH: ')
        self.lblSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Search = Text(self.search_frame,
                               height = 1,
                               width = 70)
        self.txt_Search.grid(row = 0, column = 6, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

        self.lblWordsOrPhrases = Label(self.master, text = 'WORDS/PHRASES:')
        self.lblWordsOrPhrases.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.lblWordOrPhrase = Label(self.master, text = 'Word or phrase:')
        self.lblWordOrPhrase.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,
                               selectmode='multiple',
                               height = 34,
                               width = 38)
        self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase = Text(self.master,
                                height = 1,
                                width = 40)
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExplanation = Label(self.master, text = 'Explanation:')
        self.lblExplanation.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Explanation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Explanation.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblTranslation = Label(self.master, text = 'Translation:')
        self.lblTranslation.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Translation = Text(self.master,
                               height = 10,
                               width = 40)
        self.txt_Translation.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExamples = Label(self.master, text = 'Example(s):')
        self.lblExamples.grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Example = Text(self.master,
                                height = 10,
                                width = 40)
        self.txt_Example.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = S)

    def get_word(self):
        return self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_explanation(self):
        return self.txt_Explanation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_translation(self):
        return self.txt_Translation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_example(self):
        return self.txt_Example.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def add_item(self):

        w = Word(self.get_word(), self.get_explanation(), self.get_translation(), self.get_example())

        self.words.append(w)

        self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)

        self.clear_all()

    def remove_item(self):

        self.listBox.delete(ANCHOR)
        self.words.remove()

    def edit_item(self):
        pass

    def save_item(self):
        pass

    def clear_all(self):
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Explanation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Translation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Example.delete('1.0', END)

    def refresh_all(self):
        pass

    def on_closing(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            self.master.destroy()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    gui = Vocabulary(root)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", gui.on_closing)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to reference root outside of the classes.

Comment: If you need it inside the `main()`, just use `root`. If you need it outside, then you can move `root = Tk()` outside the `main` function and it will be available everywhere.

Comment: Are you sure that is the best approach?

Comment: @wraith1337 Where do you have to access root ?

Comment: In on_closing(). I have to destroy it.